# Delete Script PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I'm beginner in PHP MySQL, all I want to know how to create a **DELETE** function for this each specific records.

[image]

Here is my code when I SELECT the records. I don't know how I will insert the DELETE function and how code structure be like.

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY agentFname ASC";

 if($result = mysql_query($sql)){
     if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {



             <table id="example" class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table">

                 <thead>

                      <tr class="headings">

              <?php           

                   echo "<th>ID</th>"; // Primary Key
                   echo "<th>Agent Code</th>"; // Unique Key
                   echo "<th>First Name</th>";  
                   echo "<th>Middle Name</th>";    
                   echo "<th>Last Name</th>";     
                   echo "<th>Contact Number</th>";     
                   echo "<th>Address</th>";     
                   echo "<th>Gender</th>";
                   echo "<th>User Type</th>"; 
                   echo "<th>Action</th>";        
                   echo "</tr>"; 
                   echo "</thead>"; 

           }  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {

               echo"<tbody>";
               echo " <tr class=\"even pointer\">"; 

               echo "<td>" .$row['user_id']. "</td>";  // Primary Key
               echo "<td>" .$row['agentCode']. "</td>";  // Unique Key
               echo "<td>" .$row['agentFname']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>" .$row['agentMname']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>" .$row['agentLname']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>" .$row['agentContact']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>" .$row['agentAddress']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>" .$row['agentGender']. "</td>";
               echo "<td>" .$row['user_type']. "</td>";
               echo "<td> <a href=\"#.php\"> Delete</a></td>"; // DELETE Function
               echo "</tr>";
                }

            }
```

Comment: I hope those are not real phone numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the user id in href with file name.

```
echo "<td> <a href="yourfile.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>"> Delete</a></td>";
```

then create your file.
example your filename.php

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM tablename where user_id='$id'");

if($sql > 0)
{
  echo "record successfully deleted";
}
else
{
 echo "errore in deleting";
}

?>
```

Comment: You're great! Thanks!

Comment: @mak mysql_query is deprecated , you shouldn't encourage the people to use, use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are tryin to do something like

```
echo "<td><a href="/yourfile.php?delete=<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>"> Delete</a></td>
```

then in `yourfile.php` you would handle the deletion and redirect back to the original page but...

This would delete the record even if you click there by mistake.

You could make little forms there with a checkbox each or have some js asking to confirm deletion first...

Comment: Thanks. but it's too close.

Comment: What I'm looking is the delete.php codes. By the way will try your suggestion using checkbox. Thanks!